# Are these elephant ear bulbs worth planting

Tags: overwintering, bulbs

[image]
My neighbor moved and said I could dig up her elephant ear bulb. It was huge when I dug it up I left it outside and it rained for 3 days and even frosted before I could do anything with it The little pieces in the picture are I guess little bulbs that came off of the big one Will any of these live???

Answer (score 1):

There is only one way to find out. Keep the bulbs frost free over winter and replant in spring. If they show any sign of rotting over winter throw them out.

The plant is not frost tolerant, but a mild overnight frost on the bulbs for just one night probably won't be fatal.

Answer (score 1):

You can't kill elephant ears unless they freeze. I have weeded out dozens and thrown the bulbs in the woods and in mulch piles . now there are elephant ears everywhere. Even small thumb size ones grow . I am in zone 8 with 50" average rainfall.